# Indirect reference not working excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Im trying to create a reference using the indirect formula in excel 2010 however the reference doesn't seem to return any results.

```
     =D53+INDIRECT("'01 07'!"&I53)
```

If i use the reference in a different way it works.

```
     =D53 + '01 07'!I53
```

Can't seem to figure out what the problem is. In the future i need the indirect formula to reference to the current sheetname.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=D53+INDIRECT("'01 07'!I53")`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Still getting invalid referece error.

Comment: Try removing & sign....if you just want the sheet name to be dynamic put sheet name in a cell. e.g. A1 and use =D53+INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!I53")

Comment: @barryhoudini .. Mmmm my mistakes .. copy paste victim :> .. thanx

Comment: @Pieter_Daems .. as barry correcting this ..